# How to convert List of <Entities> to one string with grouping?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, list

I  have a list of zones which have following columns:

```
Zone_id, ZoneName, BuildingName, CityName, RegionName
```

Now I am converting my list to string as followed:

```
var result = string.Join(", ", lstOfZones.Select(z => z.RegionName + "->" + z.CityName + "->" + z.BuildingName + "->" + z.ZoneName).ToArray());
```

and its output is like:

> North->New york->Wall Street->JbA,
>
> North->New york->Wall Street->JbB,
>
> South->Chicago->Aqua->HcA,
>
> South->Chicago->Aqua->HcB

But I want output like this:

> North->New york->Wall Street->(JbA,JbB),
>
> South->Chicago->Aqua->(HcA,HcB)

Help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this.

```
var result = string.Join(", ",  
             lstOfZones.GroupBy(z => 
                 string.Format("{0}->{1}->{2}->",
                     z.RegionName, z.CityName, z.BuildingName))
             .Select(z => string.Format("{0}({1})", 
                              z.Key, string.Join(", ", z.Select(x => x.ZoneName).ToArray())))
             .ToArray());
```

Group your items by address first. This will give you `IGrouping<string,string>`. first one is key and its addresses and second one is list of grouped items by that addresses.

Comment: And that was very quick. Faith in stackoverflow restored. :)

Comment: @Meta-Coder - You can accept it as answer if that helped you. Check this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var result lstOfZones.GroupBy(z => z.RegionName + "->" + z.CityName + "->" + z.BuildingName)
                     .Select(g=>g.Key+ "->("+ g.Agregate(String.Empty,(a,z)=>a + "," +z.ZoneName) +")")
                     .ToArray();
```

In `Aggregate` method, the first parameter sets seed start value to `String.Empty`. Second parameter defines method to concatenate current seed value (`string`) with current element